# R: Remove rows from a csv table that are outside an age range

Tags: r, postgresql

I loaded a csv table that has rows with name, age and other values into R. I am using RPostgreSQL (hope that helps).

What I want to do is filter the table, so that rows where the age is over 40 get removed. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `table[table$age<=40, ]`   ?

Comment: Thank you, I think that will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filling in as an answer.

You can restrict to the rows you want with a simple conditional.

```
table[table$age<=40, ]
```